# Jquery clone element, altering id then use keyup() not working

Tags: jquery

The Problem: When i clone 
`<div id="#cloneme1">...</div>` i get 
`<div id="cloneme2">...</div>` but the .keyup() function wont read the new DOM elements

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
      var num= $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
      var newNum= new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

      // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
      var newElem = $('#cloneme' + num).clone().attr('id', 'cloneme' + newNum);

      // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
      newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'alteredguianswer' + newNum)

      // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
      $('#cloneme' + num).after(newElem);
    });

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr("id"); // variable id = id of current textfield
                var value=$(this).val();  // variable value = value in current textfield
                $("#someplace"+id).text(value);  // edit text elsewhere on page using value
            });


<div>
     <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
</div>
     <div id="cloneme1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">Question:<input type="text" id="guianswer1" value="Answer 1" /></div>
```

I dont understand how to get a function to read the new cloned elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the keyup event for all matching elements in the DOM, but not future elements.

If you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, try using on

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // variable id = id of current textfield
    var value=$(this).val();  // variable value = value in current textfield
    $("#someplace"+id).text(value);  // edit text elsewhere on page using value
});
```

If you're using an earlier version, try using live

```
$('input[type="text"]').live('keyup', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // variable id = id of current textfield
    var value=$(this).val();  // variable value = value in current textfield
    $("#someplace"+id).text(value);  // edit text elsewhere on page using value
});
```

Comment: amazing advice! worked perfectly, and i know what to do if i upgrade to a newer version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You are only assigning the `keyup` handler to the elements that existed at the time when you defined the handler. It's like asking everyone in the empty house to dinner you just cooked, then wondering why is everyone, an hour later when they came home, still hungry.

You either need to assign the handler to each cloned element:

```
var keyupHandler = function() { ... };
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
    ...
    newElem.keyup(keyupHandler);
}
```

Or you need to take advantage of jQuery doing it for you, by using `on` instead of `keyup`:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]', function() { ... });
```

This latter form will be catching the event on all elements that match the selector that exist or *will exist later*.