# Strip out non-alpha chracters with Jquery when copying text from one input to another

Tags: jquery

On my website, I have two input fields: Title & Stock Code. I have two goals:

1. The text from the Title field should be be copied to the stock
   code field as the user enters text in the title field.
2. I also want non-alphanumeric chracters to be stripped out during
   the copy.

I have found [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515265/jquery-clone-element-altering-id-then-use-keyup-not-working) that explains how to do the first goal.
Here is my working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2gezC/1/

For the second part, I have found it hard to find a tutorial about stripping characters in Jquery, as most tutorials are for JavaScript.

I have found [this tutorial](http://php.refulz.com/validations-with-jquery-%E2%80%93-strip-whitespaces-special-characters-and-html-tags/) and have tried to integrate it into my code as follows:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('input#edit-title-fragment').keyup(function () {
            var str = $(this).val();
            str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
            var txtClone = $(this).val();
            $('input#edit-sku-fragment').val(txtClone);
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

However, it does not work. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's what you're doing:

```
// Get the user input from "this" and put it in str variable
var str = $(this).val();
// Remove all non alpha-nums from str and store it back in the str variable
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
// Get the user input from "this" (yes, again) and put it in the txtClone variable
var txtClone = $(this).val();
// Set your other textbox to be the value in txtClone
$('input#edit-sku-fragment').val(txtClone);
```

Have you spotted the mistake? You should be setting it to `str` instead.

```
$('input#edit-sku-fragment').val(str);
```

Which now works: http://jsfiddle.net/2gezC/2/

Furthmore, as the comments has noted, jQuery is a library built **on** JavaScript; it's written in JavaScript itself, as you can see by browsing it's source code; https://github.com/jquery/jquery

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect. Can you combine Javascript code with Jquery?

Comment: @big_smile: Of course; you're doing it already. `var` isn't a jQuery "thing"; it's a JavaScript way to create a variable. `replace()` is a JavaScript **String** method; nothing related to jQuery at all.